# Can I use comments in GQL when using the Google Cloud Datastore GQL editor?

Tags: google-cloud-platform, google-cloud-datastore, gql

How do I add comments in GQL when using the 'Query by GQL' editor in Google Cloud DataStore? The following don't work

```
--
#
//
/* ... */
```

The Google Cloud DataStore editor does seem to highlight the text as a comment if I use `--`, however when I run the query the following error is displayed:

`GQL Query error: Lexical error`

It doesn't say anything about comments here:

[GQL - Unsupported features and behavior differences from MySQL/Python GQL](https://cloud.google.com/datastore/docs/reference/gql_reference#unsupported_features_and_behavior_differences_from_mysqlpython_gql)

As GQL is probably most similar to MySQL, I would expect either of the following to work, as they both represent comments in MySQL:

`--`
  `#`

Answer (score 3):

Unfortunately, comments are not supported in GQL.  The 'Query by GQL' view in the Cloud Console doesn't store any past queries find a way to document your debugging queries outside of the Cloud Console.